# Dnn SPA module with WebApi works for administrators but not for Registered Users

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, dotnetnuke

I have a working Dnn SPA module based on Angular 6 which makes calls to the Dnn Service Framework. All of this works perfectly for users belonging to the administrators role, but when a user logs in with only the All Users or Registered Users roles we get the following error in Chrome Dev Console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at http.js:108
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:102)
>       at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init
>   (http.js:166)
>       at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach
>   (http.js:235)
>       at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1435)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (ReplaySubject.js:83)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (ReplaySubject.js:69)
>       at tryCatch.js:17
>       at subscribeToResult (index.js:1)

I thought that perhaps for some reason the HTTPHeaders weren't being added by our interceptor, but looking at the Network tab, none of our calls are ever being made.

Attempts at Fixing the problem:

**Check that Angular is Firing Up**
I have an app initializer in my Angular app so I added a console log to it, which is being fired:

```
export function appInitializer(configurationService: ConfigurationService) {
  configurationService.configuration.antiforgeryToken = dnnService.framework.getAntiForgeryValue();
  configurationService.apiPath = dnnService.framework.getServiceRoot(dnnService.path);
  configurationService.configuration.moduleId = dnnService.moduleId;
  configurationService.configuration.tabId = dnnService.tabId;
  configurationService.configuration.tabModuleId = dnnService.tabModuleId;
  console.log('configuration for app initializer: ', configurationService);

  return () => true;
}
```

**Check Anti-forgery Token**

One HTTPHeader that should be added is the anti-forgery token

```
dnnService.framework.getAntiForgeryValue()
```

This value for some reason is empty for Registered Users and has a proper value for Administrator users. Though, if the calls aren't even being made then I'm not sure how this could be the cause of the problem.

**Added additional logging for WebApi calls**

I found one log entry that was suspicious but wasn't able to link this to the problem:

> [WARN] DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController - Invalid tabId -1 of
>   portal 0

**Changed AccessLevel for all WebApi Controllers**
I changed all the DnnModuleAuthorisation to the following:

```
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
```

I also tried

```
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.View)]
```

Which made no difference.

**Check if first call to HTTP WebApi end point is firing**
In ngDoBootstrap I make the first HTTP call which is where things stop functioning so this would lead me to believe that there is in fact a problem in Angular:

```
 ngDoBootstrap(app) {
    console.log('about to get settings');

    this.settingsService.getSettings().subscribe((settings: Settings) => {
      console.log('fired call to get settings');  //<- Never gets here    
    });
  }
```

The console.log in getSettings().subscribe never fires!

Any hint or guidance on what else to check would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is the RequestVerificationToken. For some reason Dnn only outputs the token for administrators, or when there's a search box present in the Skin (?), which I had removed.

The workaround for this is to add the search and use styles to hide it. E.g.

```
<div id="search-top" style="display:none !important">
    <dnn:SEARCH ID="dnnSearch2" runat="server" ShowSite="false" ShowWeb="false" EnableTheming="true" Submit="Search" CssClass="SearchButton" />
</div>
```

I've tested this with non-admin users and it works.

For more information see the related [Dnn 9 bug posted on DnnTracker](https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-9279?page=com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities%3Atransitions-summary-tabpanel):

Comment: Wow, I would give you 100 upvotes if I could.  I have been fighting with this for days.  My app is an Angular 7 SPA as well, so I had a skin ascx with everything stripped out so that app fills the entire page.  I can not believe that more people are not encountering this.  I would have never figured out to add the search control to my stripped down skin file.  A huge thank you.

Comment: @JKing Glad it helped, it had me completely boggled as well!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to manually add the jQuery libraries. In Admin Mode these are added by the framework automatically. That is why you don't have errors there.

```
using DotNetNuke.Framework;
using DotNetNuke.Common;

//7.2 and lower
if (Globals.DataBaseVersion.Major < 7 || (Globals.DataBaseVersion.Major == 7 && Globals.DataBaseVersion.Minor < 2))
{
    jQuery.RequestDnnPluginsRegistration();
}
else
{
    //7.3 and higher
    JavaScriptLibraries.JavaScript.RequestRegistration(JavaScriptLibraries.CommonJs.DnnPlugins);
}
```

Comment: This is a Dnn SPA module, so I'm not sure where I would add this code? Perhaps the skin?

Comment: That's possible. The above snippet just generates some `<script src=...>` tags. You could compare the scripts from admin with non-admin and just add them in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [page](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/developers/about-modules/spa-module-development.html). You can load your anti-forgery token into your template then retrieve it in your service. It's been a while since I've worked with DNN but I remember having this exact same problem and there was an easy fix for it.

EDIT: I was able to reach out and retrieve the code I wrote for this. Here's how I retrieved the API in a pure SPA module (HTML/JS only):

```
[JavaScript:{ jsname: "AngularJs" }] 
[JavaScript:{ path: "~/DesktopModules/module/dist/app.build.js"}] 

<div id="root" 
    data-module-id="[ModuleContext:ModuleId]" 
    data-is-superuser="[ModuleContext:IsSuperUser]" 
    data-anti-forgery-token="[AntiForgeryToken:true]" 
    ng-cloak="true" 
    ng-switch="{{'[ModuleContext:IsSuperUser]'.toLowerCase()}}">
    <!-- non-admins -->
    <div ng-switch-when="false">
        <app></app>
    </div>
    <!-- admins -->
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" ng-bind="::'App'"></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.element(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('root'), ['App']);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've seen this page before and although it 'mentions' an AntiForgeryToken the next page - https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/tokens - doesn't show any AntiForgeryToken. I've tried [AntiForgeryToken] and [ValidAntiForgeryToken] but nothing works. Have you successfully used this before?

Comment: I have yes. Unfortunately I've lost my landing html. Are you using this in your main view? This is the html file you define in your .dnn file where you define which file should be used instead of an .ascx file.